# What's the difference can't load the Instagram embed code?

Tags: iframe, instagram, embed, instagram-api

I'm developing using the Instagram basic API, and I'm trying to embed an image on my site as iframe.
So, I think each image must have an embed code to get post.
But, why is the embed code disabled for images in this account? How is it different from other accounts?

`https://www.instagram.com/lilas_db9/`

Search the embed code for each image uploaded to the linked the instagram user id and import it to the site as iframe

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this account has disabled the embedding of their images for various reasons, such as privacy concerns or wanting to limit the distribution of their content. Instagram allows account owners to control the visibility of their content and determine whether it can be embedded or not.

Here is an article on how users can disable photo embedding: https://mashable.com/article/how-to-disable-instagram-embeds

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I know the feature you mentioned, but I couldn't find that option on a normal account. I don't know if Instagram doesn't provide that feature anymore, or if it's only provided to some authorized users.